# SQL query, primary key to multiple foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm having a problem which i cannot manage to fix.
I've been looking at some other posts but most of them were either to complex for me to understand/use or do not deal with the same problem.

First the tables:

Person

```
   id   |   amt
   =============
    1   |    5
    2   |    26
    3   |    3
```

Goal

```
   id   |    idPerson |  goals
   ===========================
    1   |    1        |  "AAA"
    2   |    1        |  "AAA" 
    4   |    1        |  "DDD" 
    5   |    2        |  "CCC"
    6   |    2        |  "BBB" 
    7   |    3        |  "AAA"
```

What I want:
I need all Person ids where the Person does not have the goal "AAA".
Currently a Person can only have between 1 and 3 goals in the Table Goal.

My Select:

```
 SELECT Person.id, Person.amt
 FROM Person 
 WHERE amt < 10 
 AND Person.id IN 
 (
    SELECT Goal.idPerson 
    FROM Goal 
    WHERE Person.id = Goal.idPerson 
    AND Goal.goals != "AAA"
 )
```

If possible could someone explain me why my SQL is not working and what i have to do different so it works? With an explanation i could avoid the same problem in the future. :)

Thank you.

EDIT:
I did not thought that this would make a problem but when i filter not only for 'AAA' but also for 'BBB' then it I will get results with 'AAA', 'BBB' and even some with both.
How the Where is now:

```
 AND Person.id NOT IN 
 (
    SELECT Goal.idPerson 
    FROM Goal 
    WHERE Person.id = Goal.idPerson 
    AND Goal.goals = 'AAA'
    AND Goal.goals = 'BBB'
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably looking for `NOT EXISTS` instead like

```
 SELECT Person.id, Person.amt
 FROM Person 
 WHERE amt < 10 
 AND NOT EXISTS  
 (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Goal 
    WHERE idperson = person.id AND goals = "AAA"
 )
```

Comment: I'm sorry i should have said that iam using phpmyadmin, when i try to use the SQL then i get for NOT EXISTS the message "Unrecognized keyword".

Comment: I did update phpmyadmin now i can use NOT EXISTS too but i've encountered another problem when i want to filter more than just one goal, like i described in my edit in the main post.

Comment: @SergSam, use a `IN` operator then like `AND goals IN ('AAA', 'BBB','CCC')`

Comment: With the IN operator it works now, thank you @Rahul!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it to be correlated and you want to use `NOT IN` instead:

```
select Person.id,
    Person.amt
from Person
where amt < 10
    and id not in (
        select idPerson
        from Goal
        where goals = 'AAA'
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `NOT IN` rather than `IN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE amt < 10 
 AND Person.id NOT IN (
        SELECT idPerson FROM Goal WHERE goals = 'AAA'
  );
```

Comment: Thank you, this works if i use one criteria, but when i try to select all where not 'AAA' and not 'BBB' it wont working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Also change this:

```
 AND Goal.goals != "AAA"
```

to

```
 AND Goal.goals != 'AAA'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subselect filters all rows that do not match "AAA". That includes "DDD". You can use

```
SELECT * FROM Person p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT g.id FROM Goal g WHERE g.goals="AAA" AND g.idPerson=p.id)
```